# LinkedIn social plugin - <script> with both src and content

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn [Share Plugin Generator](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator), which suggests using the following code:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
```

What could the `lang: en_US` be doing in that first `<script>` element? Surely it is invalid for there to be both a `src` attribute *and* content?

Comment: It's not invalid, but is ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't invalid, it just never gets passed to the JavaScript parser.

It is there to be accessed via DOM by the script.

Comment: Having de-obfuscated the JavaScript I can see how this is done. The `console.warn` of `"script tag contents must be key/value pairs separated by a colon."` is a dead giveaway.